# ASIO proper handling of multiple threads + strand + socket + timer

Tags: c++, server, boost-asio, asio

I'm using the latest ASIO version(as of this time 1.18.0). Currently designing a multithreaded asynchronous TCP server with timers(for timeouts). I have a single `io_context` with multiple threads calling its `run()` function. I accept new connections like this:

```
void Server::AcceptConnection()
{
    acceptor_.async_accept(asio::make_strand(io_context_),
            [this](const asio::error_code& error, asio::ip::tcp::socket peer) {
                if (!error) {
                    std::make_shared<Session>(std::move(peer))->run();
                }
                AcceptConnection();
            });
}
```

And here a stripped down version of the `Session` class:

```
class Session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Session>
{
public:
    Session(asio::ip::tcp::socket&& peer) : peer_(std::move(peer)) {}
    void run()
    {
        /*
        asio::async_read(peer_, some_buffers_, some_callback_);
        timeout_timer_.expires_after();
        timeout_timer_.async_wait();
        // etc
        */
    }
    
private:
    asio::ip::tcp::socket peer_;
    asio::steady_timer timeout_timer_{peer_.get_executor()};
}
```

Please note the initialization of the timer.
Also, beware that I'm not using any kind of `strand::wrap()` or `asio::bind_executor()` wrappers for the async handlers of the socket and the timer, because of what I understood, they are no longer required if I initialize my objects with the proper executors.

**The question here is:** Is that a correct way of handling TCP connection inside a strand with a timer inside the same strand that the TCP connection is using?

Note: The timer is used to abort the TCP connection if the timeout passes.

Comment: If ever there was a question that deserved an upvote, it's this one. It's hard to understand why this simple technique isn't in the examples, but if it's there, I sure can't find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is the way I write the things as well, using the new interfaces.

I remember having the same concerns when I started out using the new interface, and ended up *checking* that the various completion handlers do run on the expected strand, which they do.

All in all, these result in significant simplifications in library usage.

Comment: This does indeed eliminate just a mountain of complexity from the usage. Strange that it's not better documented, really.

Comment: @AllanBazinet The only way to "better" document is by detailing how it was (not uniform) and how it has become as a change. That's bound to generate more confusion. IMO the "design/why" sections of the documentation are very under-appreciated (e.g. [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview.html)) and there is of course the [changelog](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/boost_asio/history.html#:~:text=Added%20support%20for%20the%20proposed%20standard%20executors). I do think that some better "news feed" is very welcome.

Comment: thanks for clarifing it. I think that how-to examples are missing in the documentation. In particular, before-after examples. Smashing my head to get the new idea... mostly done, thanks to you both too :)