# boost::asio Strictly sequential invocation of event handlers using strand

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-asio

I have a question regarding to the usage of strand in boost::asio framework.
The manuals refer the following

> In the case of composed asynchronous operations, such as async_read()
> or async_read_until(), if a completion handler goes through a strand,
> then all intermediate handlers should also go through the same strand.
> This is needed to ensure thread safe access for any objects that are
> shared between the caller and the composed operation (in the case of
> async_read() it's the socket, which the caller can close() to cancel
> the operation). This is done by having hook functions for all
> intermediate handlers which forward the calls to the customisable hook
> associated with the final handler:

Let's say that we have the following example
Strand runs in a async read socket operation .  Socket read the data and forwards them to a async writer socket.  Two operation are in the same io_service. Is this write operation thread safe as well?Is is called implicity in the same strand? Or  is it  needed  to explicitly call async_write in the  strand

```
read_socket.async_read_some(my_buffer,
    boost::asio::bind_executor(my_strand,
      [](error_code ec, size_t length)
      {
           write_socket.async_write_some(boost::asio::buffer(data, size), handler);
      }));
```

Is the async_write_some sequential executing in the following example or needs strand as well?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, since you bound the completion handler to the strand executor (explicitly, as well), you know it will be invoked on the strand - which includes `async_write_some`.

Note you can also have an implicit default executor for the completion by constructing the socket on the strand:

```
 tcp::socket read_socket { my_strand };
```

In that case you don't have to explicitly bind the handler to the strand:

```
read_socket.async_read_some( //
    my_buffer, my_strand, [](error_code ec, size_t length) {
      write_socket.async_write_some(asio::buffer(data, size), handler);
    });
```

I prefer this style because it makes it much easier to write generic code which may or may not require strands.

> **Note** that the quoted documentation has no relation to the question because none of the async operations are composed operations.

Comment: I would like to understand better what the "simplified" usage of strand. It's not clear you could use a strand in this way at all, from the documentation. Have you some good pointers? Thanks

Comment: @Sigi You already found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64036518/85371). I guess one can explain why async operations don't document the executor choice, because it is not relevant depending on the type of `CompletionToken`. The mechanics of _that_ is documented [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/model/completion_tokens.html). Aside of witnessing the executors used, you can also inspect the code [e.g.](https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/blob/master/asio/include/asio/basic_stream_socket.hpp#L1150).

Comment: You could even do reciprocal reasoning: if you look at the [AsyncReadStream](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/AsyncReadStream.html), it has requires the `async_read_some` **and** `get_executor` interface. The requirement must serve a purpose, and if not to bind to (intermediate) handlers for composed operations, I cannot think of a reason.